# Browser.Document.frames works on one computer on another not

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba, frames

I have an Excel VBA tha works on one computer but gives an error on other computers.
 This is the code I use:

```
Set Browser = New InternetExplorer
Browser.navigate "http://core.purus.se/PurusWeb/common/frameset.aspx?
Profile=Sweden&NamedPath=Golvbrunnar"
Do While Browser.Busy: DoEvents: Loop: Do Until Browser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
Sleep 100
Browser.Visible = True
Set Document = Browser.Document.frames("Main").Document
Set htmlColl = Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

And this is the error message: "... -2147352319 (80020101) ... 'frames' in object 'JScriptTypeInfo' ..."

I get the error on the row: "Set Document...."

The computer it works on has WindowsVista 32-bit, InternetExplorer 9 and MS Office 2007.
 The computer that gets the error has Windows7 64-bit, InternetExplorer 11 nd MS Office 2010.